# One-to-Many Relationship type is not showing in Studio - SugarCRM

Tags: php, relationship, one-to-many, sugarcrm

I am working in Sugarcrm 7.8 I am trying to create a relationship between contacts and my custom module example myorder but its not showing in type field when I select my custome module in `Related Module'.

[image]

I couldnt able to find any doc which explains such situation. How i can make a one-to-one relationship through studio when its not showingup. I really dont like to create through code as it breaks operations while we try to retrive report. If i work through studio its fine.

Any how i tried creating the follwing files to see if it shows any relationship.

> src/custom/Extension/application/Ext/TableDictionary/contacts_myorder_1.php
>   src/custom/metadata/contacts_myorder_1MetaData.php

But it creates a new relationship via code.

**Has anyone been able to achieve anything similar?**

Community Question: https://community.sugarcrm.com/message/94195-one-to-many-relationship-type-is-not-showing-in-studio

Comment: In my experience, some of them are just inexplicably restricted to One to One within Studio.

Comment: Thank you for also sharing the community link and the answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some deep research found that, In my custom module i should have explained the relationship between the modules.

After creating the follwoing file. I could able to see the relationships.

> src/modules/mycustomodule/clients/base/layouts/subpanels/subpanels.php
>   src/modules/mycustomodule/vardefs.php

**Content: subpanels.php**

```
array (
            'layout' => 'subpanel',
            'label' => 'LBL_MYCUSTOMMODULE_SUBPANEL_CONTACTS',
            'context' => array (
                'link' => 'mycustommodule_contacts',
            ),
        ),
```

**Content: vardefs.php**

```
'mycustommodule_contacts' => array(
            'name'         => 'mycustommodule_contacts',
            'type'         => 'link',
            'relationship' => 'contacts_mycustommodule',
            'module'       => 'Contacts',
            'bean_name'    => 'Contact',
            'source'       => 'non-db',
            'vname'        => 'LBL_MYCUSTOMMODULE_CONTACTS_LINK',
        ),
```

After **Repair & Rebuild**. It works as expected. Hope it helps someone.!